# Validate in dojo dialog with messages like a simple xpage

Tags: dojo, xpages

I´d like to validate in the dijit dialog like in a simple xpage with disableClientSideValidation="true".
When I use a custom control in a xpage show messages but if I put in dijit the dialog closes without validation

I´m using a button with client script --> dijit.byId(ID of div).show();

In the div ID is a custom control with this code:

```
<xp:inputText id="input1" style="width:160px;" role="button" title="used to text" required="true"  disableClientSideValidation="true">
   <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateRequired><xp:this.message><![CDATA[The value is empty]]>
        </xp:this.message></xp:validateRequired>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>
<xp:messages id="messagesReq"></xp:messages>
<xp:button id="test" value="test">
     <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
     </xp:eventHandler>
/xp:button>
```

How to submit or save the form in the custom control, but first showing messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog closes because you are refreshing the full page, so dojo is reconstructing the dialog again hidden. I recoment you use the `<xe:dialog>` from the extention library:

```
<xe:dialog id="XSPdialog">
    <xp:panel>
                  <!-- your code -->
    </xp:panel>
</xe:dialog>
```

The `<xe:dialog>` constructs a iframe so you can change/validate/save all datasources on it and dispaly the responses. Another solution would be to move your dialog content to a seperate XPage and add an `iframe` to your dialog Content:

```
<div id="dojoDialog"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog"
    title="My Dialog Title">
    <xp:panel tagName="iframe">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="src">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript: context.getUrl().toString().split(view.getPageName())[0] + "/dialogContent.xsp"}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs>
    </xp:panel>
</div>
```

Another possibility would be to validate your fields on the client side.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I use the <xe:dialog> from the extention library and now I can validate in the dialog